# How can I generate a boolean expression recursively in Python Hypothesis?

Tags: property-based-testing, python-hypothesis

I'm new to Python's Hypothesis library and property based testing in general. I want to generate arbitrarily nested policy expressions with the following grammar:

> ((A and B) or C)

I'm feeling that the recursive strategy is what I want, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to use it. The code I have only seems to generate one "level" of expression. Here's what I have:

```
import unittest

from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.strategies import text, composite, sampled_from, characters, recursive, one_of


def policy_expressions():
    return recursive(attributes(), lambda base_strategy: one_of(base_strategy, policy_expression()))

@composite
def policy_expression(draw):
    left = draw(attributes())
    right = draw(attributes())
    gate = draw(gates())
    return u' '.join((left, gate, right))


def attributes():
    return text(min_size=1, alphabet=characters(whitelist_categories='L', max_codepoint=0x7e))


def gates():
    return sampled_from((u'or', u'and'))


class TestPolicyExpressionSpec(unittest.TestCase):

    @given(policy_expression=policy_expressions())
    def test_policy_expression_spec(self, policy_expression):
        print policy_expression
        assert policy_expression # not empty
```

How might I generate arbitrarily nested policy expressions using Hypothesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might do what you want.

```
import unittest

from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.strategies import text, composite, sampled_from, characters, recursive, one_of


def policy_expressions():
    return one_of(attributes(), policy_expression())

@composite
def policy_expression(draw):
    left = draw(policy_expressions())
    right = draw(policy_expressions())
    gate = draw(gates())
    return u' '.join((left, gate, right))


def attributes():
    return text(min_size=1, alphabet=characters(whitelist_categories='L', max_codepoint=0x7e))


def gates():
    return sampled_from((u'or', u'and'))


class TestPolicyExpressionSpec(unittest.TestCase):

    @given(policy_expression=policy_expressions())
    def test_policy_expression_spec(self, policy_expression):
        print policy_expression
        assert policy_expression # not empty

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct way is this, to take `base_strategy` as an argument of `policy_expression`:

```
def policy_expressions():
    return recursive(attributes(), policy_expression)

@composite
def policy_expression(draw, base_strategy):
    left = draw(base_strategy)
    right = draw(base_strategy)
    gate = draw(gates())
    return u' '.join((left, gate, right))
```

The accepted answer not using `recursive` is likely to run into the problems described in the [Generating recursive data](https://hypothesis.works/articles/recursive-data/) post in the Hypothesis blog.